# Adding Dynamic row in table, but it is emptying data in the row

Tags: javascript, angular

What am I doing wrong here. Need help.

When I click on "Add" button, the data I selected in the rows of table are becoming blank. But When I select Delete button and then click on Add button, then it not emptying of one time only. If I see console, I can see data there, but it is not showing up on the screen.
[image]
[image]
Here is my code:

html:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="row111">
                        <label for="Select Image" class="col-sm-311 col-form-label111">Add Threshold and Notification for this Inspection: </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="float-right">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" (click)="addNotification()">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Threshold</th>
                        <th>Notification Level</th>
                        <th>Message</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <!-- <tr> -->
                     <tr *ngFor="let notification of notificationArray; let i = index">
                        <td>{{i+1}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control" maxlength="50" readonly
                                       required
                                       id="threshold"
                                       name="notification.thresholdId"
                                       [(ngModel)]="notification.thresholdId"  
                                        #threshold="ngModel" >
                                        <option value="0" selected> Select </option>
                                        <option *ngFor="let threshold of thresholdList" value="{{threshold.thresholdId}}" >
                                              {{threshold.threshold}}
                                        </option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input [(ngModel)]="notification.notificationLevel" required class="form-control" type="text" name="notification.notificationLevel" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input [(ngModel)]="notification.message" required class="form-control" type="text" name="notification.message" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-default"  type="button" (click)="deleteNotification(i)">Delete</button>

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>

    </div>
```

component.ts:

```
notificationArray: Array<NotificationLevel> = [];
newNotification: any = {};
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.newNotification = {thresholdId: "0", notificationLevel: "", message: ""};
    this.notificationArray.push(this.newNotification);
}
addNotification(index) {

    this.newNotification = {thresholdId: "0", notificationLevel: "", message: ""};
    this.notificationArray.push(this.newNotification);
    console.log(this.notificationArray);  // I can see all entered data in console
    return true;
}

deleteNotification(index) {
    if(this.notificationArray.length ==1) {
        alert("At least one Notification Required for an Inspection");
        return false;
    } else {
        this.notificationArray.splice(index, 1);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe after creating new row you have a copy of each ngModel that you have in initial row. That's why they  vanish.

Comment: when you are saying "have a copy of each ngModel that you have in initial row", what does that mean? can you please elaborate a little. And any suggestions?

Comment: Have u got any solution, Cause i have same problem.

Comment: @MohaiminMoin: I did it. But honestly I forgot it how I did. I can't see the code because the requirement got changed completely shortly after I finished this page. But I see (in your answer) you did it as well. Thanks and Good Luck in your project. :)

Comment: yeah i did,,but don't exactly know why he behaves like that :(

Answer (score 2):

Ok, solve the problem:-

The main problem is in `name=""` attribute. `name=""` must differ in each row .We can solve it in two ways:

1) Either Change the `name=""` attributes name dynamically so that for every row it has a different name, i did it to add index number with it as

```
<input [(ngModel)]="notification.notificationLevel" name="notificationThreshold{{i}}" required class="form-control" type="text" />
```

2) Or avoid `name=""` and so We can avoid `[(ngModel)]` By `[value]` and `(input)` and can use as like :-

```
 <input [value]="notification.notificationLevel" (input)="notification.notificationLevel=$event.target.value" required class="form-control" type="text"/>
```

Comment: i have been trying your the first solution but am still getting the last input value only are you sure the first solution you have specified here is correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In fact, all of your `notificationArray` elements is the same instance of `newNotification`. By doing this : `this.newNotification = {thresholdId: "0", notificationLevel: "", message: ""};` you actually reset the first line too because of it.

Try to store `newNotification` in a var instead :

```
notificationArray: Array<NotificationLevel> = [];
newNotification: any = {};
ngOnInit(): void {
    var newNotification = {thresholdId: "0", notificationLevel: "", message: ""};
    this.notificationArray.push(newNotification);
}
addNotification(index) {
    console.log(this.notificationArray);
    // here is the correction
    var newNotification = {thresholdId: "0", notificationLevel: "", message: ""};
    this.notificationArray.push(newNotification);
    console.log(this.notificationArray);
    return true;
}

deleteNotification(index) {
    if(this.notificationArray.length ==1) {
        alert("At least one Notification Required for an Inspection");
        return false;
    } else {
        this.notificationArray.splice(index, 1);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**update :**

I don't know if it's related but you'll have duplicate `threshold` id on your select. Use your `i` to make it unique.
It's the same for your input names. You should add `[]` after the field name otherwise only the last row will be submit.

I added a `console.log` of you array after the push. Can you tell in comment if the first index is reset at this point ?

Comment: no luck. If I write let newNotification = {th ..., it throws compile error. So changed it to let newNotification: any = {};
        newNotification = {thr ..., at least no error. But it is vanishing the data as it used to.

Comment: And if you use var instead of let ?

Comment: same result. vanishing

Comment: Added console.log after pushing into Array and can see data in console, but not in UI. fyi: threshId is coming from database. I can see in console, it is unique and When I submit the form, I can get all data entered and able to send to Java controller.

Answer (score -1):

Of course the row is cleared because you are clearing it:

`this.newNotification = {thresholdId: "0", notificationLevel: "", message: ""};`

So on clicking the add button, the bound values are overridden and then you are pushing it into the array. Thus they are cleared :)

Comment: So what is your solution ?

Comment: I checked it now, copy-pasted your ts and html as new component, this is what I see: notification level, message are empty then I enter some data, then I hit "add" -> line 1 stays the same (not empty) and line 2 will be added as empty line. I think you said you got both rows empty after hitting "add".. can you show us the full code somehow?

Comment: and the new row is always empty because you are specifically adding {thresholdId: "0", notificationLevel: "", message: ""} element to the notification array, which represents an empty row