# Angular 4: Add dynamic row and get data in Controller

Tags: angular, typescript

I am really confused and not getting how to proceed. Need some help please...

Requirement:

I am trying to add dynamic rows in a simple for and get the values in controller so I can send to java.

What I have done so far:

I have written the below code which adds a new row when I click on "Add" button and deletes a row when  I click on "Delete" button

Problem:

1) At first I wrote name="notification.message". Here when I enter some value in the text box and then click on "Add" button, it does add a new row, but it erases the entered data in the first row.

2) To resolve this I wrote name="{{notification.message}}". See here the name is wrapped by brackets. Now it does NOT erase the entered data in the first row. So I was thinking I got it...   BUT when I see console, I am getting below error.

3) I have written same code like wrapping the name in select type (i.e. drop down). But here it erases the selected value when I add a new row. And in console there is no error (like the below error whcch I am getting only for input type text,

I have asked my [earlier question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50723261/adding-dynamic-row-in-table-but-it-is-emptying-data-in-the-row) with screenshots.

Code:

```
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Threshold</th>
                    <th>Notification Level</th>
                    <th>Message</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <!-- <tr> -->
                 <tr *ngFor="let notification of notificationArray; let i = index">
                    <td>{{i+1}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <select class="form-control" maxlength="50" readonly
                                   required
                                   id="threshold"
                                   name="{{notification.thresholdId}}"
                                   [(ngModel)]="notification.thresholdId"  
                                    #threshold="ngModel" >
                                    <option value="0" selected> Select </option>
                                    <option *ngFor="let threshold of thresholdList" value="{{threshold.thresholdId}}" >
                                          {{threshold.threshold}}
                                    </option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input [(ngModel)]="notification.notificationLevel" id="notificationLevel" #notificationLevel="ngModel" required class="form-control" type="text" name="{{notification.notificationLevel}}" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input [(ngModel)]="notification.message" id="message" #message="ngModel" required class="form-control" type="text" name="{{notification.message}}" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-default"  type="button" (click)="deleteNotification(i)">Delete</button>

                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

TS:

```
thresholdList: Threshold[];
notificationArray: Array<NotificationLevel> = [];
newNotification: any = {};
addNotification(index) {

    //var newNotification: any = {};
    //newNotification = {};
    this.newNotification = {thresholdId: "0", notificationLevel: "", message: ""}
   // setTimeout(() => this.newNotification = {thresholdId: "0", notificationLevel: "", message: ""}, 2000);
   //  this.notificationArray.push({'thresholdId': "0", 'notificationLevel': "", 'message': ""});

 //   var medData = new NotificationLevel()   // creating object of your model class
    this.notificationArray.push(this.newNotification) ;

    console.log(this.notificationArray);
    return true;
}

deleteNotification(index) {
    console.log(this.notificationArray);
    if(this.notificationArray.length ==1) {
        alert("At least one Notification Required for an Inspection");
        return false;
    } else {
        this.notificationArray.splice(index, 1);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
ERROR Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
      control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

      Example 1: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">
      Example 2: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

Comment: `id="message" ="ngModel"` do you have this line in your code?

Comment: My bad. Typo... corrected

Comment: Have you enclose the table with a form tag ?

Comment: yes, otherwise it will throw parse error